# initializationError while executing Robolectric JUnit 4 test case

Tags: android, junit4, robolectric

I am facing initializationError while executing Robolectric JUnit 4 test case.
Development IDE : Eclipse Indigo 3.7.2

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/robolectric/annotation/Config
```

Please find source code of my test case below:

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
public class MainActivityTest {

    @Test
    public void clickingSplashVideo_shouldStartCategoryActivity() throws Exception {

        MainActivity activity = Robolectric.setupActivity(MainActivity.class);
        activity.findViewById(R.id.myvideoview).performClick();

        String hello = activity.getString(R.string.app_name);
        assertThat(hello, CoreMatchers.equalTo("Hello world!"));

        Intent expectedIntent = new Intent(activity, CategoryActivity.class);
        assertThat(Shadows.shadowOf(activity).getNextStartedActivity(), CoreMatchers.equalTo(expectedIntent));
    }
}
```

Comment: Show us you build.gradle. If you run test from command line does it fail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just solved this problem by adding **robolectric-2.3-jar-with-dependencies.jar** and removed existing **robolectric-3.0-rc3.jar** from Android project build path

Comment: So downgrading robolectric is the only solution?